# ExtJS: Put tools onto the title bar

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have been able to put tools into window title bars before, but would like to be able to do the same thing to a Panel.

This was my attempt:

```
panel = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'my_panel',
    region: 'west',
    title:'MyTitle',
    iconCls:'helpIcon', 
    initComponent:function(){
        var config = {
            tools:[{
                id: 'gear',
                handler:  function(){...}
            }]
        };
        Ext.apply(this, config);
        Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config);          
        Ext.Panel.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    }           
}
```

Some advice would be greatly appreciated

JJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous posts are correct, but I thought I would explain why what you are doing is wrong.

You are completely redefining the `initComponent` method of `Ext.Panel` in the object you are creating, and the default `Ext.Panel.initComponent` needs to run in order to setup things like `tools`.

In your code, when you call `Ext.Panel.superclass.initComponent`, you are calling `Ext.BoxComponent.initComponent`, not the existing `Ext.Panel.initComponent`.

In order to do special `initComponent` things, and then call up to `Ext.Panel.initComponent`, you need to create an extension of `Ext.Panel`:

```
MyPanelClass = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    id: 'my_panel',
    region: 'west',
    title:'MyTitle',
    iconCls:'helpIcon', 
    initComponent:function(){
        var config = {
            tools:[{
                id: 'gear',
                handler:  function(){...}
            }]
        };
        Ext.apply(this, config);
        Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config);          
        MyPanelClass.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    }

});
```

And then later:

```
var mypanel = new MyPanelClass();
```

Comment: Yes, but... in this case a subclass is definitely overkill, and seemingly not the OP's intention. Just add tools as a config item as posted by others and don't mangle initComponent.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this was simply an abstraction of the full context of the piece of code, this IS what I was looking for, so thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You seems to have mixed up with many things in your code. You seems to be trying to extend the panel and use `region` property. The `region` property is used for border layout.

here is how:

```
 panel = new Ext.Panel({ 
    id: 'my_panel', 
    title:'MyTitle',
    iconCls:'helpIcon', 
    tools:[{        
        id: 'gear', 
        handler:  function(){...}     
    }]
});
```

If you need to extend you will have to use the Ext.extend() method.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

```
panel = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'my_panel',
    region: 'west',
    title:'MyTitle',
    iconCls:'helpIcon', 
    tools:[{
        id: 'gear',
        handler:  function(){...}
    }]
};
```